# There isn't /etc/gdm/gdm.schema

Tags: gnome, gdm

I read some guides on GDM (I want to create an invisible user in GDM login screen) but they refers to a file called `/etc/gdm/gdm.schema` that there isn't on my computer.

This is the content of my `/etc/gdm`:

```
config-error-dialog.sh  greeter.gsettings  PostLogin    PreSession
custom.conf             Init               PostSession  Xsession
```

Is one of these files equivalent to gdm.schema, need I to create one or is there an error in the GDM installation?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en) the file `gdm.schema` should not be present in `/etc/gdm` directory. Perhaps if you tell us what's your problem, we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to hide an user in GDM preferences.
To hide the user, I changed its PID to a number lower than 1000, then I rebooted the computer.
Now the user is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and add or change the `Exclude` directive in the `[greeter]` section:

```
[greeter]
Exclude=nobody,user,user1
```

Users `user` and `user1` won't be shown on the list at the login screen but can still log in by typing their name and password (if they have a password).

[Credits to user Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64499/how-to-create-a-user-that-doesnt-show-up-on-the-login-screen)

Answer (score 1):

#### Tested on Ubuntu 19.04; kernel 5.0.0-13-generic

Run:

```
sudo vim  /var/lib/AccountsService/users/"$your_user"
```

Replace

```
SystemAccount=false
```

with

```
SystemAccount=true
```

---

You don't need to edit gdm.schemas to hide a user. But if you want to know where it is:

Have a look here

```
/usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Tested on Arch Linux.
The user I wanted to exclude didn't exist yet, but you can copy the configuration file from another user (e.g. your default user) and edit it.